# Refactor React code, to use Redux state from a Firebase RT database & Redux Hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, react-hooks

I have been setting up a website/React App using a boilerplate I've previously used that has Redux & Firebase database integrated. However I am using React Hooks in a project using this boilerplate for the first time. So far I have no problems fetching data from the Firebase RT-DB and using it with useState and useEffect. I now want to refactor my code to store my app's state in Redux but still use functional components and leveraging Hooks also.

I'm having trouble putting all of it together.

My setup currently looks like this... I'm not authenticating any data from Firebase, just pulling the data straight in. I've included my homepage component as an example which has 2 basic pieces of state/data from Firebase db {firstName} & {lastName}.

To clarify my issue, I'm having trouble with fetching the data from the real-time database inside the action generator and then dispatching it to the reducer function.

I've included what I think the action should look like, but I'm not sure if that's correct and then what the reducer function should look like.

Any help, is appreciated.

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store/configureStore';
import AppRouter, { history } from './routers/AppRouter';

// const store = configureStore();

const jsx = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter history={history} />
  </Provider>

);

ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export const reducers = combineReducers({

});

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

// store.js

export function configureStore(initialState = {}) {

  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

  return store;
}

export const store = configureStore();
```

**homepage.js component example**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import database from '../firebase/firebase';

const HomePage = () => {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(firstName);
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(lastName);

    useEffect(() => {
        database.ref()
            .once('value')
            .then((snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val();
                const { firstName, lastName } = data
                setFirstName(firstName)
                setLastName(lastName)
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log('Error fetching data', e);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
         <div className="homepage-section__content">
            <HomePageTitle firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} />
         </div>
    )
}

export { HomePage as default };
```

**homePageTitle.js component**

```
import React from 'react';

const HomePageTitle = (props) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h1>
            {props.firstName}
            <span>{props.lastName}</span>
        </h1>
    </React.Fragment>
);

export { HomePageTitle as default };
```

Comment: Seems you could use standard actions to dispatch an action to fetch from the DB, use a thunk to handle the async logic, and dispatch a success action to update your redux store. What have you tried? Can you include your actions and reducer(s)? Is there a particular aspect or issue you have?

Comment: I've not tried anything yet, as I'm not sure how to do it. I'm aware there are Redux hooks, useReducer & useSelector but how I integrate them, I'm not sure. This is basically my problem. I think I need to move the database fetch in to an action, but how I then get it in to the reducer and then the store, I'm note sure how to.

Comment: `react-redux` has `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks, `useReducer` is a standard React hook, unrelated to redux (but applying a very similar pattern). If you are already familiar with `react-redux` then dispatching an action is essentially just the same as it was previously when using "mapDispatchToProps" except now it's no longer a prop, and the action creators are exactly the same. If using the hooks is still a bit confusing you can still use the older `connect` Higher Order Component you might be more familiar with. From here we could help get it working or converted to use the hooks.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to use the hooks. This is my first time fetching data from firebase inside Redux also, so it's completely new to me. Any help or pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a way you could port over the local component state and `useEffect` callback into redux state and actions.

You could define a set of data fetch initiate, success, and failure actions.

```
const setDataLoading = loading => ({
  type: "FETCH_DATA_LOADING",
  payload: loading,
});

const fetchDataSuccess = payload => ({
  type: "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
  payload, // { firstName, lastName }
});

const fetchDataFailure = () => ({ type: "FETCH_DATA_FAILURE" });

const fetchData = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setDataLoading(true)); // <-- start loading
  return database.ref() // <-- return Promise chain
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const { firstName, lastName } = snapshot.val();
      dispatch(fetchDataSuccess({ firstName, lastName }));
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error('Error fetching data', e);
      dispatch(fetchDataFailure());
    })
    .finally(() => dispatch(setDataLoading(false))); // <-- complete loading
};
```

Define your reducer. The `FETCH_DATA` action kicks off the asynchronous action to fetch the data, clears any current error state, and sets `loading` to true. Upon success or failure the loading state is cleared and either the name data is stored or an error value is set.

```
const initialState = {
  error: false,
  loading: false,
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "FETCH_DATA_LOADING":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload,
      };

    case "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: false,
        ...action.payload, // ...{ firstName, lastName }
      };

    case "FETCH_DATA_FAILURE":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Add reducer to store.

```
import userReducer from './path/to/reducer/above';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
});
```

Wire up `HomePage` to redux store.

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { error, firstName, lastName, loading } = useSelector(state => state.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="homepage-section__content">
      {error && <div>Error fetching user name</div>}
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingSpinner />
      ) : (
        <HomePageTitle firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: This works perfectly and the explanation is awesome!